# How to write to a custom event log with c++ (unmanaged, NO .net framework)

Tags: c++, logging, manifest, native

I was not able to understand how to log to a custom event log using c++.
I will explain better: googling around for hours I discovered that the most recent way to use windows log should be that named "Windows Event Log" built on top of ETW (here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I want that my log events shows in EventViewer under "Application and services logs"\"MyAppCustomLog"

So I did these steps
- Edited registry creating the MyAppCustomLog entry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\EventLog\MyAppCustomLog)

- created an Instrumentation Manifest (xml file) using the SDK utility "ecmangen", creating the manifest file MyAppLog.man
- built the .rc and .bin and .h files using message compiler: mc -um MyAppLog.man -h . -z MyAppLog
- registered the manifest using the wevtutil this way: wevtutil im MyAppLog.man
- create a simple consolle application that calls the in MyAppLog.h (the header created by message compiler) in this way:

  ...
  ULONG result = EventRegisterMyAppLog();
  ...
  EventWriteMyAppLogSimpleEvent();
  ...
  EventUnregisterMyAppLog();
  ...

But if I execute those methods where does the event go? How can I associate it to my custom event log? I could not figure it out...

Am I doing the wrong thing?
I am sure that some pieces are missing from my puzzle but which ones?
My question is: how to link the event I defined in manifest (MyAppLogSimpleEvent) to the custom event log MyAppCustomLog that I see in event viewer?
Could someone explain me how to set a relation between my events and the custom log? 
In case this is the wrong way to do this (write events defined in some kind of manifest in a custom event log) could you please explain me what do I have to do?
Thank you very much for any help